# I want to know how to completely delete a module in SuiteCRM

Tags: module, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I made a module and changed its name before completing the process and now its not functioning. I tried to create a new module with a lil different name but when I try to add fields it throws an error that says -

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'modules/sss_Bag_From_Vendor/sss_Bag_From_Vendor.php'
>   (include_path='/home/streetst/public_html/crm:/home/streetst/public_html/crm/include/HTMLPurifier/standalone:/home/streetst/public_html/crm/include/..:.:/usr/local/php54/pear')
>   in /home/streetst/public_html/crm/include/utils/autoloader.php on line
>   75

Answer (score 1):

If you can still access SuiteCRM web interface you can use module loader to disable OR  uninstall the package. You will likely want to delete the package as well. If you can't access the web interface you can remove the modules manually from the include/modules.php file.